# Building 0 byte file on Xcode 8.2 causes warning "Mach-O: Reached end of file while looking for: uint32_t."?

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, firebase

I recently downloaded the latest Google Maps SDK for iOS (Ver.2.1.1) and Firebase SDK for iOS (Ver. 3.11.1) and installed them manually to XCode 8.2.

The building was succeeded but I got the following warnings,**"Mach-O: Reached end of file while looking for: uint32_t.".**

```
warning: ../Frameworks/Google/GoogleMapsCore.framework/Versions/A/Headers/GoogleMapsCore.h: Failed to parse Mach-O: Reached end of file while looking for: uint32_t.
warning: ../Frameworks/Google/Firebase/Database/FirebaseDatabase.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeSignature: Failed to parse Mach-O: Reached end of file while looking for: uint32_t.
```

I know the kind of warnings can be normally solved by deleting some files in DerivedData folder, but couldn't do that this time.

a common thing in the files that i could find is 0 byte size.

**../GoogleMapsCore.framework/Headers**

```
-r-xr-x---  1 ****  staff     0  1 20 14:42 GoogleMapsCore.h
```

**../FirebaseDatabase.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeSignature**

```
-r-xr-xr-x@ 1 ****  staff     0  1 11 15:24 CodeSignature
```

I'd like to know if anyone already know this solution for this issue.
Thx.

Comment: I'm having the same warning show up for the `FirebaseDatabase` framework. I can run my app, though I haven't started calling any code from that framework yet. You found any fix yet, or do you think we're just waiting for an update?

Comment: Thx for your comment.
I have no idea what to do for the moment、but seemingly it's a negligible issue. We'd better wait and see the update, I think :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. 

Comment: Does any one got any solution for this?

Comment: Any solution to this yet?

Comment: i knew i didn't meet such warnings when i installed the frameworks through CocoaPods. i dunno y though.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error because my Mac froze and I had to restart it during frameworks copy to build folder so one of them was broken. A project clean solved the issue. Basically this error should mean that a framework binary is broken.